# why does my custom-made "cursor" falls behind the moving div elements when i hover over them?

Tags: javascript, html, css

hello everyone hope you guys are having a great day!
so, i am building a simple game where I use a custom-made cursor as the aim for shooting div elements moving around the screen as the enemies and when i apply the "pointerdown" event i want the enemy to change its color. however, every time i hover over the enemy the cursor falls behind witch i don't understand why, and when i use the z-index property it will prevent the "pointerdown" event from firing. if some cool OG programmer can help me, it would mean a lot to me.

**style**

```css
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
cursor: none;
}

.aim {
position: absolute;
background: black;
width: 10px;
height: 10px;
border-radius: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.enemy {
position: absolute;
border: 3px solid black;
background-color: blue;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
}
```

**javascript**

```
const body = document.body;
const aim = document.createElement("div");
const enemy = document.createElement("div");

body.appendChild(aim);
body.appendChild(enemy);

aim.classList.add("aim");
enemy.classList.add("enemy");

let enemy_X_position = 0;
let enemy_Y_position = 0;
let enemy_X_distance = 1;
let enemy_Y_distance = 1;

function Flight()
{
    enemy.style.left = enemy_X_position + "px";
    enemy.style.top = enemy_Y_position + "px";
}

setInterval(function()
{
    enemy_X_position += enemy_X_distance;
    enemy_Y_position += enemy_Y_distance;

    if ((enemy_X_position + enemy.offsetWidth) >= window.innerWidth || enemy_X_position <= 0)
    enemy_X_distance = -enemy_X_distance;

    if ((enemy_Y_position + enemy.offsetHeight) >= window.innerHeight || enemy_Y_position <= 0)
    enemy_Y_distance = -enemy_Y_distance;

    Flight();
},1000/60)

window.onmousemove = function()
{
    aim.style.left = event.pageX + "px";
    aim.style.top = event.pageY + "px";
}

enemy.onpointerdown = function()
{
    event.target.style.background = "red";
}

enemy.onpointerup = function()
{
    event.target.style.background = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

The event is not triggering because `pointerdown` was received by `aim` when it sits on top of `enemy`.

To solve this, add `pointer-events: none` on `aim` class to prevent it from being the target of a pointer event.

[More about `pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

Hope this will help!

```
.aim {
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

  pointer-events: none;
}
```

**Original**

Perhaps an over simplified solution, but it seems that if you reverse the order of `appendChild`, the `aim` should be stacked over `enemy` without additional styling.

Example:

```
body.appendChild(enemy);
body.appendChild(aim);
```

Because both elements are child of `body`, Unless there is other styling that override this stacking, the later one should be on top.

Comment: I tried it but still prevents the event from firing

Comment: @Johnnygarcia I updated the answer, hopefully it will help address this issue.

Comment: my guy thnks for the eye opening on this one

Comment: @Johnnygarcia Glad that it works! I added a link to some more information about this, in case you're interested. Also if it helps, please accept this answer so the post is complete. Thanks.